# How to use openWhisk forwarder combinator to forward parameters around a cloudant action

Tags: openwhisk

I have this scenario where I want to check if user's email is already been used when trying to signup and throw an error “user already exists” in that case.

here’s what my sequence looks like:

`Input action` -> `CloudnAnt EXE QUERY-Find` -> `Validate email action` -> `CloudnAnt create User/Throw user already exists error action`

my json payload looks like this : 
`{email: 'blahblah@domain.com', pass: "pass"}`

the problem is that I have no control over the output of the cloudnant predefined actions, and by that I lose the payload after the 2nd action "CloudnAnt EXE QUERY-Find User with email action"

[image]

Is there a way to keep my input all the way through the sequence? and could the forward combinator be the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try `/whisk.system/combinators/forwarder`, which lets you pass arguments to an action and then specify arguments that get sent to the *next* one. Ie, I've got 5 arguments, let's pass 1 and 2 on to the next item in the sequence, and when done, pass 3, 4, 5 to the next one. I believe the output from the first item goes along as well.

Comment: Ok I can confirm, the result from the thing you call is passed automatically. I'm working on a blog post to make this clearer, but let me know if it helps.

Comment: I am a bit lost here, where would the combinator fit in this sequence I provided, before the cloudant action? and how would it work if I have no control over the output of the cloudant action?

Comment: Let me add some context. Given a sequence of A, B, C and B is the one you can't control, you replace B in the sequence with a call to forwarder. You tell forwarder to run B, use arguments so and so, and pass a list of other arguments onward to C. C will also get whatever B outputs.

Comment: This may help - let me know and I can add more context here since SO isn't a fan of links: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/08/05/working-with-the-forwarder-action-in-openwhisk/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple, just replace the cloudant action with a forward combinator which will invoke the cloudant action and forward the parameters around it.

to invoke a cloudant action you need get the full path for your action and that includes the namespace and the database name like the following:

`/namespace/dbname/actionName`

in my case it was `/sansan/users/exec-query-find`

so if you want to check whether the email exists or not in your cloudant db, and keep the original params just pass the following payload to your cloudant action

```
{
    "data":{...},// some data you want to keep after the cloudant query
    "query": {
      "selector": {
        "email": "email@domain.com"
      }
    },
    "$actionName": "/sansan/users/exec-query-find",
    "$forward": [// list of params you want forward
        "data"
    ],
    "$actionArgs": [ // list of params you want to feed the action
       "query"
    ]
}
```

after running the sequence, the output should look like this:

```
{
    "data": {...}, // your data
    "docs": [...]// cloudant query results
}
```

the forward combinator is poorly documented, but you can find more details about it in [Raymond Camden's blog post](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/08/05/working-with-the-forwarder-action-in-openwhisk/)

look at Raymond's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497226/how-to-use-openwhisk-forwarder-combinator-to-forward-parameters-around-a-cloudan#comment78002612_45512846) too